# KEPServerEx OPC-UA Server Methods/Events

Tags: c#, opc-ua, kepserverex

I have been looking around this topic and haven't found something helpful yet. I am looking to add an custom Method/Event on the KEPServerEx Server, just for testing against the client.

I ccouldn't find, if KEPServerEx offer this feature in trial version.

I found some official examples from OpcFoundation on how to create a seperate OpcUa server Application (C#). But I am looking forward to a simple testing.

Or is there another tool which could help in this case better?